# FirebaseMessaging.h File not Found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am building a Flutter project that integrates Firebase, but I am having trouble building the project on XCode because I keep receiving the error "FirebaseMessaging.h" not Found.

I have verified that FirebaseMessaging.h does indeed exist in my project folder. It exists inside the path "/Users/<username>/Desktop/MVP/<app_name>/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources".

Here are the things I have tried:
- Deleting Pods folder and Podfile.lock
- Pod Install
- Uninstall / reinstall XCode
- Verified that my Podfile is correct
- Updating the "Header Search Paths" Setting within my Xcode.

Here is what my Header Search Paths looks like within my Xcode:
[Header Search Paths pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47hVj.png)
[Header Search Paths pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVrZ4.png)
I have also added "/Users/<username>/Desktop/MVP/<app_name>/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources" inside the header Search Paths as well.

This is my Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.11.1'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.11.1'
end
```

Comment: [Github issue documented](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10815) They are using **Flutter** and **Firebase** too.